# Formula in hyperbolic quadrilateral with one point on the absolute

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I am asked to show that for a hyperbolic quadrilateral with $3$ right angles and one point on the absolute with finite sides of length $a,b$ then

> $$\sinh(a)\sinh(b)=1$$

I have constructed a line so that I can use the angle of parallelism formula but I'm a bit stuck at this point.

I'd really appreciate any help!

**Edit**: I have the complimentary angles of parallelism as suggested below but I'm still a little stuck on how to apply these without long caluculations which I can't seem to get to work out.

Comment: The angle of parallelism for $a$ is complementary to the angle of parallelism for $b$.